# How escape function with single and double quotation in?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

i am trying to use `doctrine` date format function, in orded to compare date in `m-d` with today `m-d` don't know how to handle escape in my `addWhere`, here is a snippet:

```
->andWhere('date("m-d", strtotime('r.dateOfDeath')) = :now')
->setParameter('now',\date("m-d", time()))
```

Comment: Did you try either escaping them via \ (backslash) or just changing to one type of quotation?

Comment: yes i did, i think the problem start from date function i have tried to escape it using (\) and it didn't resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to search by dateOfDeath with a specific month/day combination, you will probably find Doctrine lacking.

In MySQL you would generally do `WHERE MONTH(r.dateOfDeath) = MONTH(NOW()) AND DAY(r.dateOfDeath) = DAY(NOW())`
To make it easy for yourself you could just use a Native MySQL query, see ex. [Execute raw SQL using Doctrine 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325012/execute-raw-sql-using-doctrine-2)

In Doctrine the DAY, NOW and MONTH functions are missing. The now part you can solve with a parameter. The DAY AND MONTH functions you'd need to implement through a bundle like: https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions

Another possible solution might be to simply make dateOfDeath a string and do a `->andWhere("r.dateOfDeath LIKE '%:md')->setParameter('md', date('m-d'))`

Comment: my problem is about comparing record date in format of `m-d` with now date in format of `m-d`, the use of DateTime will use time.

Comment: I updated the answer to better reflect your question.

Comment: Many thanks @Rein i need to vote up for your answer but i need 15 reputation score :)

Answer (score 0):

I have resolve the problem using doctrine extension [see]: https://github.com/uvd/Doctrine/tree/master/UVd/DoctrineFunction "UVD Doctrine"

**config.yml**

```
 orm:
    default_entity_manager: default
    entity_managers:
        default:
            connection: default
            dql:
                datetime_functions:
                    DATE_FORMAT: AppBundle\Extension\Doctrine\DateFormat
```

**Usage**

**register function**

```
 protected function registerDateFunctions() 
 {
    $emConfig = $this->getEntityManager()->getConfiguration();
    $emConfig->addCustomStringFunction('DATE_FORMAT','AppBundle\Extensions\Doctrine\DateFormat');
  }
```

**create Query Builder**

```
 public function getAllRecords()
{
    $this->registerDateFunctions();
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
        ->select('r')
        ->addSelect('d')
        ->addSelect('b.country')
        ->leftJoin('r.religion', 're')
        ->leftJoin('r.country_of_birth', 'b')
        ->leftJoin('r.country_of_death', 'd')
        ->where('r.status = :status')
        ->setParameter(':status', 1)
        ->andWhere("DATE_FORMAT(r.dateOfDeath,'%m-%d') = :now")
        ->setParameter(':now',\date("m-d", time()))
        ->getQuery();
    return $qb->getArrayResult();

}
```

credit: "http://www.uvd.co.uk/blog/using-mysqls-date_format-in-doctrine-2-0/"