# Manually writing DQL

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-1.2

I am trying this part in the [Doctrine Documentation](http://symfony.com/blog/call-the-expert-retrieving-data-with-doctrine) wherein you can:

---

**Manually writing DQL**

For you SQL buffs, we didn't forget about you. You can optionally write your DQL queries manually and parse them in to a Doctrine_Query instance or just execute them.

```
$dql = "FROM User u, u.Phonenumbers p";
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()->parseQuery($dql);
```

Or you can just execute them by using the query() method of Doctrine_Query.

```
$dql = "FROM User u, u.Phonenumbers p";
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()->query($dql);
```

---

Yet I'm having difficulties since I've encountered the following error:

> Attempted to load class "Doctrine_Query" from namespace "AppBundle\Controller".
>   Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

Could you please help me with this?

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use AppBundle\Entity\TblProduct;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $products = "SELECT * FROM TblProduct";
        $q = Doctrine_Query::create()->query($products);

        if (!$products) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException(
                'No products registered yet.'
            );
        }
        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', array('products' => $products));
    }
```

Comment: Ahh so it's not part of Doctrine2 anymore? I was just trying this one. I'm still new to Symfony. :)

Comment: read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9945711/1055200

Comment: Also, the particular error message is a namespace issue.  $q = \Doctrine_Query... (note the back slash) would get you past it but don't use D1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is part of **[Doctrine 1.2](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/ormold/1.2/class-Doctrine_Query.html)** and not **[Doctrine 2.5](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.5/index.html)**. In the latest version you would just create queries in the **[Doctrine Query Language](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html)** with `createQuery()`.

```
<?php
$dql = "FROM User u, u.Phonenumbers p";
$query = $em->createQuery($dql);
$users = $query->getResult();
```

Alternatively you can write **[Native SQL](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html)**.