# Doctrine and Symfony2: How to execute raw queries (General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while > other unbuffered queries are active)

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to execute a raw query using Doctrine into the Symfony framework.

Here there is the code:

```
class MessagesHandler
{
    /** @var \Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager The entity manager used to access entities */
    protected $em = null;

    public function __construct($em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function getMessagesToPost($user)
    {
        $query = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `messages` WHERE `posted_by` = ' . $user->getId() . ' AND `message_posted` = 0';

        return $this->em->getConnection()->exec($query);
    }
```

I have set the class MessagesHandler as a service:

```
services:
    shq.handler.Messages:
                class: AppBundle\Handler\MessagesHandler
                arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
```

Now, when I execute the code, I receive the following error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while
>   other unbuffered queries are active. Consider using
>   PDOStatement::fetchAll(). Alternatively, if your code is only ever
>   going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting
>   the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.")...

**How can I use `PDOStatement::fetchAll()`?**

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Comment: Could you try to call $em->getConnection()->fetchAll() or $em->flush before you call your query ? Dump the result to see if it's important data you might be fetching and that you want to keep somewhere.

Comment: Could you have an `em->flush()` missing somewhere ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `createNativeQuery` method:

```
$query = $entityManager->createNativeQuery('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `messages` WHERE `posted_by` = ? AND `message_posted` = 0', $rsm);
$query->setParameter(1, $user->getId());

$count = $query->getResult();
```

Documentation available here: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html

Comment: It seems to me a little bit complex just to execute a count query, isn't it? Is there a more simple way to achieve the same result? I want only a simple count.

Comment: If you do `$query->getSingleScalarResult()` you get the number directly in your `$count` variable. I don't see why this is complex? I do the same query as you do but I use a parameterized one (to prevent sql injection).

Comment: You used the $rsm variable that is a new class I have to create, or not?

Comment: Thank you for the advice about getSingleScalarResult()!

Comment: @Aerendir please read the documentation. You should use the result mapping which is the `$rsm`

Answer (score 0):

As the suggested solutions seems too much complicate to me, I continued to search for a more simple solution and I came up with this:

```
public function getMessagesToPost($user)
{
    $query = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `messages` WHERE `posted_by` = :userId AND `message_posted` = 0';

    $params = array(
        'userId' => $user->getId()
        );

    /** @var \Doctrine\DBAL\Statement $preparedQuery */
    $preparedQuery = $this->em->getConnection()->prepare($query);
    $preparedQuery->execute($params);

    $result = $preparedQuery->fetch();

    // Return the first value of the returned array
    return array_shift($result);
}
```

Inpiration form [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27140447/1399706).