# how use sql query in Symfony

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

how can i write native sql queries with doctrine in symfony ?

Comment: "Complex queries" is very abstract. What do you mean by this ? Writing raw SQL ? DQL ? You can still write raw SQL in Doctrine thanks to the Doctrine DBAL layer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325012/execute-raw-sql-using-doctrine-2/9945711#9945711

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$connection = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getConnection();
```

$connection is now a class Doctrine\DBAL\Connection check the docs http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.1/class-Doctrine.DBAL.Connection.html

This code should help you.

```
$connection = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getConnection();
$query = "
  INSERT INTO data (
      name
    , age
  ) VALUES (
      ?
    , ?
  )
";
$connection->executeQuery(
   $query
 , array(
      'test'
    , 30
   )
 , array(
     \PDO::PARAM_INT   
    ,\PDO::PARAM_STR
  )
);
```

Or

```
$connection = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getConnection();

$name = 'test';
$age = 31;

$query = "
  INSERT INTO data (
      name
    , age
  ) VALUES (
      :name
    , :age
  )
";

$statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindValue("name", $name, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->bindValue("age", $age, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->execute();
```