# Convert SQL To Doctrine in Symfony

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I have three tables and two relations. One table is many to many and the other table is one to many relation. I created a query in mysql but I'm not converting to `dql` or `querybuilder` in Symfony.
Sample query is:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `resturant` LEFT JOIN `food` ON `resturant`.`id` = `food`.`resturant_id` 
WHERE `food`.`name` LIKE "%pizza%" 
GROUP BY `resturant`.`name`
```

Comment: `LEFT JOIN \`food\`.\`food\` ON ` is typo? or it is `LEFT JOIN \`food\` ON `?

Comment: Sory ```LEFT JOIN `food` ON``` is Ok

Comment: Looks like you're only joining two tables there. Would help immensely if you added your doctrine entity relations to your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute raw SQL using Doctrine 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325012/execute-raw-sql-using-doctrine-2)

Answer (score 0):

food entity in my project

```
<?php

namespace Food\AdminBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Food
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="food")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Food\AdminBundle\Repository\FoodRepository")
 */
class Food
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="contents", type="string", length=500, nullable=true)
     */
    private $contents;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="price", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $price;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="approve", type="boolean")
     */
    private $approve;

    /**
     * @var \Food\AdminBundle\Entity\Category
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Food\AdminBundle\Entity\Category")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE" )
     * })
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * @var \Food\AdminBundle\Entity\Resturant
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Food\AdminBundle\Entity\Resturant")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="resturant_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE" )
     * })
     */
    private $resturant;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Food
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set contents
     *
     * @param string $contents
     *
     * @return Food
     */
    public function setContents($contents)
    {
        $this->contents = $contents;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get contents
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getContents()
    {
        return $this->contents;
    }

    /**
     * Set approve
     *
     * @param boolean $approve
     *
     * @return Food
     */
    public function setApprove($approve)
    {
        $this->approve = $approve;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get approve
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getApprove()
    {
        return $this->approve;
    }

    /**
     * Set category
     *
     * @param \Food\AdminBundle\Entity\Category $category
     *
     * @return Food
     */
    public function setCategory(\Food\AdminBundle\Entity\Category $category = null)
    {
        $this->category = $category;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get category
     *
     * @return \Food\AdminBundle\Entity\Category
     */
    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->category;
    }

    /**
     * Set resturant
     *
     * @param \Food\AdminBundle\Entity\Resturant $resturant
     *
     * @return Food
     */
    public function setResturant(\Food\AdminBundle\Entity\Resturant $resturant = null)
    {
        $this->resturant = $resturant;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get resturant
     *
     * @return \Food\AdminBundle\Entity\Resturant
     */
    public function getResturant()
    {
        return $this->resturant;
    }

    /**
     * Set price
     *
     * @param integer $price
     *
     * @return Food
     */
    public function setPrice($price)
    {
        $this->price = $price;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get price
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getPrice()
    {
        return $this->price;
    }
}
```

Resturant entity

```
<?php

namespace Food\AdminBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
/**
 * Resturant
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="resturant")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Food\AdminBundle\Repository\ResturantRepository")
 */
class Resturant
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="logo", type="string", length=30, nullable=true)
     */
    private $logo;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="duration", type="string", length=150, nullable=true)
     */
    private $duration;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="address", type="string", length=800, nullable=true)
     */
    private $address;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="minimal", type="integer")
     */
    private $minimal;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="delivery", type="integer")
     */
    private $delivery;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="score", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $score;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="cost", type="integer")
     */
    private $cost;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="startlunch", type="time", nullable=true)
     */
    private $startlunch;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="endlunch", type="time", nullable=true)
     */
    private $endlunch;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="startdinner", type="time", nullable=true)
     */
    private $startdinner;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="enddinner", type="time", nullable=true)
     */
    private $enddinner;


    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Food\AdminBundle\Entity\Zone", inversedBy="Resturant")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="resturant_has_zone",
     *   joinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="resturant_id", referencedColumnName="id" )
     *   },
     *   inverseJoinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="zone_id", referencedColumnName="id" )
     *   }
     * )
     */

    private $zone;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Food\AdminBundle\Entity\Food", mappedBy="Resturant")
     */
    private $food;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Resturant
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set logo
     *
     * @param string $logo
     *
     * @return Resturant
     */
    public function setLogo($logo)
    {
        $this->logo = $logo;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get logo
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLogo()
    {
        return $this->logo;
    }

    /**
     * Set duration
     *
     * @param string $duration
     *
     * @return Resturant
     */
    public function setDuration($duration)
    {
        $this->duration = $duration;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get duration
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDuration()
    {
        return $this->duration;
    }

    /**
     * Set address
     *
     * @param string $address
     *
     * @return Resturant
     */
    public function setAddress($address)
    {
        $this->address = $address;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get address
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAddress()
    {
        return $this->address;
    }

    /**
     * Set minimal
     *
     * @param integer $minimal
     *
     * @return Resturant
     */
    public function setMinimal($minimal)
    {
        $this->minimal = $minimal;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get minimal
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getMinimal()
    {
        return $this->minimal;
    }

    /**
     * Set delivery
     *
     * @param integer $delivery
     *
     * @return Resturant
     */
    public function setDelivery($delivery)
    {
        $this->delivery = $delivery;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get delivery
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getDelivery()
    {
        return $this->delivery;
    }

    /**
     * Set score
     *
     * @param integer $score
     *
     * @return Resturant
     */
    public function setScore($score)
    {
        $this->score = $score;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get score
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getScore()
    {
        return $this->score;
    }

    /**
     * Set cost
     *
     * @param integer $cost
     *
     * @return Resturant
     */
    public function setCost($cost)
    {
        $this->cost = $cost;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get cost
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getCost()
    {
        return $this->cost;
    }

    /**
     * Set startlunch
     *
     * @param \DateTime $startlunch
     *
     * @return Resturant
     */
    public function setStartlunch($startlunch)
    {
        $this->startlunch = $startlunch;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get startlunch
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getStartlunch()
    {
        return $this->startlunch;
    }

    /**
     * Set endlunch
     *
     * @param \DateTime $endlunch
     *
     * @return Resturant
     */
    public function setEndlunch($endlunch)
    {
        $this->endlunch = $endlunch;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get endlunch
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getEndlunch()
    {
        return $this->endlunch;
    }

    /**
     * Set startdinner
     *
     * @param \DateTime $startdinner
     *
     * @return Resturant
     */
    public function setStartdinner($startdinner)
    {
        $this->startdinner = $startdinner;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get startdinner
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getStartdinner()
    {
        return $this->startdinner;
    }

    /**
     * Set enddinner
     *
     * @param \DateTime $enddinner
     *
     * @return Resturant
     */
    public function setEnddinner($enddinner)
    {
        $this->enddinner = $enddinner;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get enddinner
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getEnddinner()
    {
        return $this->enddinner;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->zone = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add zone
     *
     * @param \Food\AdminBundle\Entity\Zone $zone
     *
     * @return Resturant
     */
    public function addZone(\Food\AdminBundle\Entity\Zone $zone)
    {
        $this->zone[] = $zone;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove zone
     *
     * @param \Food\AdminBundle\Entity\Zone $zone
     */
    public function removeZone(\Food\AdminBundle\Entity\Zone $zone)
    {
        $this->zone->removeElement($zone);
    }

    /**
     * Get zone
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getZone()
    {
        return $this->zone;
    }

    /**
     * Add food
     *
     * @param \Food\AdminBundle\Entity\Food $food
     *
     * @return Resturant
     */
    public function addFood(\Food\AdminBundle\Entity\Food $food)
    {
        $this->food[] = $food;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove food
     *
     * @param \Food\AdminBundle\Entity\Food $food
     */
    public function removeFood(\Food\AdminBundle\Entity\Food $food)
    {
        $this->food->removeElement($food);
    }

    /**
     * Get food
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getFood()
    {
        return $this->food;
    }


    /**
     * @Assert\File(
     * maxSize="2m",
     * mimeTypes = {"image/jpeg", "image/png"},
     * mimeTypesMessage = "Please upload a valid Image File"
     *
     * )
     */
    private $file;


    // Uploading File LOL


    /**
     * Sets file.
     *
     * @param UploadedFile $file
     */
    public function setFile(UploadedFile $file = null)
    {
        $this->file = $file;
    }

    /**
     * Get file.
     *
     * @return UploadedFile
     */
    public function getFile()
    {
        return $this->file;
    }


    public function getAbsolutePath()
    {
        return null === $this->logo
            ? null
            : $this->getUploadRootDir() . '/' . $this->logo;
    }

    public function getWebPath()
    {
        return null === $this->picture
            ? null
            : $this->getUploadDir() . '/' . $this->logo;
    }

    protected function getUploadRootDir()
    {
        // the absolute directory path where uploaded
        // documents should be saved
        return __DIR__ . '/../../../../web/' . $this->getUploadDir();
    }

    protected function getUploadDir()
    {
        // get rid of the __DIR__ so it doesn't screw up
        // when displaying uploaded doc/image in the view.
        return 'upload/resturant/logo';
    }

    public function upload()
    {
        // the file property can be empty if the field is not required
        if (null === $this->getFile()) {
            return;
        }

        // use the original file name here but you should
        // sanitize it at least to avoid any security issues

        // move takes the target directory and then the
        // target filename to move to


        $stringArray = explode(".", $this->getFile()->getClientOriginalName());
        $suffix = $stringArray[count($stringArray) - 1];
        $this->logo = $this->random_string() . '.' . $suffix;


        $this->getFile()->move(
            $this->getUploadRootDir(),
            $this->logo
        );

        // clean up the file property as you won't need it anymore
        $this->file = null;
    }

    private function random_string($hashstring = null, $randLengh = null)
    {
        $string = $hashstring;
        $randLengh = 15;
        if ($string == null) {
            $string = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
        }
        $charactersLength = strlen($string);
        $randomString = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $randLengh; $i++) {
            $randomString .= $string[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
        }

        return $randomString;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->getName();
    }
}
```

and zone entity and relation

```
<?php

namespace Food\AdminBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Zone
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="zone")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Food\AdminBundle\Repository\ZoneRepository")
 */
class Zone
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=100, unique=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="approve", type="boolean")
     */
    private $approve;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Zone
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set approve
     *
     * @param boolean $approve
     *
     * @return Zone
     */
    public function setApprove($approve)
    {
        $this->approve = $approve;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get approve
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getApprove()
    {
        return $this->approve;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->getName();
    }
}
```