# sql query not working for doctrine 2

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM UserWfl ";
$query = $em->createQuery($sql);
$d = $query->getResult();
var_dump($d);
```

Reference link: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html

**error is coming**:

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 7: Error: Expected IdentificationVariable |
>   ScalarExpression | AggregateExpression | FunctionDeclaration |
>   PartialObjectExpression | "(" Subselect ")" | CaseExpression, got '*'

Comment: SQL will not work with doctrine look for an equivalent DQL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute raw SQL using Doctrine 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325012/execute-raw-sql-using-doctrine-2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

createQuery It is a function for DQL. SQL is different. Doctrine use createNativeQuery function for SQL.

http://www.doctrine-project.org/2009/08/15/doctrine2-native-queries.html for more detail

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$sql = "SELECT u FROM UserWfl u";
$query = $em->createQuery($sql);
$d = $query->getResult();
var_dump($d);
```