# Custom query without using doctrine relation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I need to create a custom query, without using the doctrine relationship on Symfony 5.4.
I have two entities : Orders and Carrier. This two entities / tables are joined through the column 'id_carrier' (it's the same for both entities). When i execute my query, i get this error:
[image]
So i thought to customize the query without passing the association. Can i do this?

I tried also to write the SQL query directly ('SELECT o.* FROM en_orders o INNER JOIN en_carrier c ON c.id_carrier = o.id_carrier), but it not work.

**Orders.php**

```
  <?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\OrdersRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=OrdersRepository::class)
 */
class Orders
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id_order;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $module;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $payment;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $ps_reference;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $en_reference;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $details;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $invoice;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=20, scale=6, nullable=true)
     */
    private $total_paid_tax_inclu;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=20, scale=6)
     */
    private $total_products_wt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=10, scale=0, nullable=true)
     */
    private $total_shipping;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=10, scale=0, nullable=true)
     */
    private $carrier_tax_rate;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $order_note;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=App\Entity\Carrier::class, mappedBy="id_carrier")
     */
    private $id_carrier;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=OrderDetail::class, mappedBy="id_order")
     */
    private $orderDetails;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="CartProduct", mappedBy="id_cart")
     */
    private $id_cart;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity=State::class, cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_state", referencedColumnName="id_state")
     */
    private $id_state;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity=Address::class, cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_address_delivery", referencedColumnName="id_address")
     */
    private $id_address_delivery;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity=Address::class, cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_address_invoice", referencedColumnName="id_address")
     */
    private $id_address_invoice;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->orderDetails = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getIdOrder(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id_order;
    }

    public function getModule(): ?string
    {
        return $this->module;
    }

    public function setModule(?string $module): self
    {
        $this->module = $module;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPayment(): ?string
    {
        return $this->payment;
    }

    public function setPayment(string $payment): self
    {
        $this->payment = $payment;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPsReference(): ?string
    {
        return $this->ps_reference;
    }

    public function setPsReference(?string $ps_reference): self
    {
        $this->ps_reference = $ps_reference;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEnReference(): ?string
    {
        return $this->en_reference;
    }

    public function setEnReference(?string $en_reference): self
    {
        $this->en_reference = $en_reference;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDetails(): ?string
    {
        return $this->details;
    }

    public function setDetails(?string $details): self
    {
        $this->details = $details;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getInvoice(): ?int
    {
        return $this->invoice;
    }

    public function setInvoice(?int $invoice): self
    {
        $this->invoice = $invoice;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTotalPaidTaxInclu(): ?string
    {
        return $this->total_paid_tax_inclu;
    }

    public function setTotalPaidTaxInclu(?string $total_paid_tax_inclu): self
    {
        $this->total_paid_tax_inclu = $total_paid_tax_inclu;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTotalProductsWt(): ?string
    {
        return $this->total_products_wt;
    }

    public function setTotalProductsWt(string $total_products_wt): self
    {
        $this->total_products_wt = $total_products_wt;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTotalShipping(): ?string
    {
        return $this->total_shipping;
    }

    public function setTotalShipping(?string $total_shipping): self
    {
        $this->total_shipping = $total_shipping;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCarrierTaxRate(): ?string
    {
        return $this->carrier_tax_rate;
    }

    public function setCarrierTaxRate(?string $carrier_tax_rate): self
    {
        $this->carrier_tax_rate = $carrier_tax_rate;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getOrderNote(): ?string
    {
        return $this->order_note;
    }

    public function setOrderNote(?string $order_note): self
    {
        $this->order_note = $order_note;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->date;
    }

    public function setDate(?\DateTimeInterface $date): self
    {
        $this->date = $date;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIdCarrier(): ?OrderCarrier
    {
        return $this->id_carrier;
    }

    public function setIdCarrier(?OrderCarrier $id_carrier): self
    {
        // unset the owning side of the relation if necessary
        if ($id_carrier === null && $this->id_carrier !== null) {
            $this->id_carrier->setIdOrder(null);
        }

        // set the owning side of the relation if necessary
        if ($id_carrier !== null && $id_carrier->getIdOrder() !== $this) {
            $id_carrier->setIdOrder($this);
        }

        $this->id_carrier = $id_carrier;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, OrderDetail>
     */
    public function getOrderDetails(): Collection
    {
        return $this->orderDetails;
    }

    public function addOrderDetail(OrderDetail $orderDetail): self
    {
        if (!$this->orderDetails->contains($orderDetail)) {
            $this->orderDetails[] = $orderDetail;
            $orderDetail->setIdOrder($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeOrderDetail(OrderDetail $orderDetail): self
    {
        if ($this->orderDetails->removeElement($orderDetail)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($orderDetail->getIdOrder() === $this) {
                $orderDetail->setIdOrder(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIdCart(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id_cart;
    }

    public function setIdCart(?int $id_cart): self
    {
        $this->id_cart = $id_cart;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIdState(): ?State
    {
        return $this->id_state;
    }

    public function setIdState(?State $id_state): self
    {
        $this->id_state = $id_state;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIdAddreddDelivery(): ?Address
    {
        return $this->id_address_delivery;
    }

    public function setIdAddreddDelivery(?Address $id_address_delivery): self
    {
        $this->id_address_delivery = $id_address_delivery;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIdAddressInvoice(): ?Address
    {
        return $this->id_address_invoice;
    }

    public function setIdAddressInvoice(?Address $id_address_invoice): self
    {
        $this->id_address_invoice = $id_address_invoice;

        return $this;
    }
    
}
```

**Carrier.php**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\CarrierRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="en_carrier")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=CarrierRepository::class)
 */
class Carrier
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=App\Entity\Orders::class, inversedBy="id_carrier")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_carrier", referencedColumnName="id_carrier")
     */
    private $id_carrier;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $name;

    public function getIdCarrier(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id_carrier;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(?string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

OrdersRepository.php

```
/**
 * @return Orders[] Returns an array of Orders objects
 */
public function getFilteredOrders(): array
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('o')
        ->select('o')
        ->innerJoin('o.en_carrier','c','WITH','o.id_carrier = c.id_carrier')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
    ;
}
```

Comment: So where exactly does `en_carrier` come form?  On a broader note you seem to be ignoring advice from your previous question.  You are not quite getting the notion that entities are objects and having properties with names like `id_carrier` is misleading and confusing.  An Orders entity has a relation to a Carrier entity, not a carrier_id.  Until you internalize the distinction then you will continue to have problems.  You should really take the time and work through a few of the basic examples in the docs.

Comment: And I'm pretty sure you want to use a [ManyToOne relation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-one-unidirectional) as opposed to a OneToMany.  You also seem to have an entity called OrderCarrier floating around.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('o')
     ->select('o, c')
     ->innerJoin('o.id_carrier', 'c')
     ->getQuery()
     ->getResult()
;
```

If you really want to make a query without the QueryBuilder, you can use DQL, but it is not recommanded (for example, to be safe with SQL injections). You can have more informations here :

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.11/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html

Comment: Did you mean raw sql instead of `DQL` ? Because using doctrine query language mean that you will have to use the query builder. Also raw sql can still be safe from SQL injection by using prepared statements: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69885184/11350193

Comment: @Léane Barboitin what if i use this approach? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325012/execute-raw-sql-using-doctrine-2)

Comment: Yes, you just have to be careful with SQL Injection, you're right @Dylan Kas

Comment: @s.lafrag it could work, not the best way, I learnt that it's better if you use the querybuilder as much as possible...