# Symfony - Doctrine - SQL SERVER - CAST error

Tags: sql, sql-server, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a text field in SQL Server. I can't change the type.
And I need to do a group by...
My code :

```
 $queryBuilder= $this->createQueryBuilder('a');
 $queryBuilder ->select('a.MyfieldText');
 $queryBuilder ->groupBy('a.MyfieldText');
```

The result is:

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or ordered except when using the LIKE or IS NUL operator.

In SQL server manager studio this query it's ok :

```
SELECT cast(a.MyfieldText as varchar(250)) FROM TABLE GROUP BY cast(a.MyfieldText as varchar(250))
```

If i modify my query in symfony :

```
$queryBuilder ->select('cast(plt.pckliLInfo as varchar(255)));
```

I have this message :

> Error: Expected known function, got 'cast'

What is good practice ?

Comment: Yes but I can't change the db

Comment: Then you're stuck with needing to convert/cast the value; which could well be awful for performance. Though why are you converting to a `varchar(255)`? `text` can hold *up to* 2 **billion** characters and it's usage denotes the value is likely to have more than **8,000** characters.

Comment: because SQL server does not allow group by on text , and i have max 180 characters

Comment: Then *why* (again) are you using `text`? `text` has been deprecated since *2005* and was for when you have values that are likely to be 8,000 characters or more in length (prior to the additional of `MAX` length). If the value will be at most 180 characters there is **no reason** to be using that data type. Fix the design.

Comment: Because I can not modify the structure of the database. 
There are related business applications

Comment: Then get whomever can to fix it. *That* is your real solution.

Comment: CAST is not included in DQL, you could either create it yourself or use raw sql https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325012/execute-raw-sql-using-doctrine-2/69885184#69885184

Comment: Seems like even more of a reason that that OP needs to fix the design then, @DylanKAS . The data type is deprecated, the data type *can't* be grouped on, the data type isn't appropriate (it's too large for the data they are storing) and they can't even `CAST` (or `CONVERT`?) it natively in the language they are using. Do we need any more nails?